# Moment.js in object each undercore.js

Tags: underscore.js, momentjs

I'm trying to converver one ISODate date, mongodb pattern, but it is giving error, I put me back to String an outdated function error.

I do not know is the return of each of the underscore.

Code:

https://jsbin.com/xahesugoka/edit?html,js,console

Comment: The code is in the jsbin.

Comment: JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/xahesugoka/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I think that your test data may be a problem. Does mongo give you back a string or an integer for the datetime? https://jsbin.com/saruxupoca/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: integer, this a response: [1442376658212, 1442463058212, 1442549458212, 1442639027161, 1442722258212, 1442811827161, 1442895058212]

Comment: in response : date
 
 Object { $date=1442376658212}
$date
 
 1442376658212

Comment: I see two issues in your jsbin. First, the `$date` for `teste1` is a string not a number and that's why you get an error. Change it to a number and the message goes away.  Second problem: can you show us what you expect as output?  The way you `_.each()` is coded, only the first element will be processed since the `return` will stop processing.  Show us what you expect in `var date = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your JS Bin [code](https://jsbin.com/yenarinabi/edit?html,js,console), I see couple of issues here. First you need to apply Number on $date as it seems it can have both strings and numbers as well. Secondly in _.each you need to pass date property not the whole object to moment. Third _.each wouldn't return anything. _.each will iterate over the list of objects and call callback method.

Updated code will look like some thing as follows

```
var data = [
  {
    "testes": "teste1",
    "date": {
      "$date": "1442895058213",
      "guests": 10
    }
  },
    {
    "testes": "teste2",
    "date": {
      "$date": 1367046000001,
      "guests": 10
  }
  }
];

var test = _.pluck(data, "date");
console.log(test);
 _.each(test, function(d) { 
     var dt = moment(Number(d.$date));
     console.log(dt.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')); 
 });
```